# Pagespeed on app engine.. lots of issues. am i missing something?.. [php, appengine]

Tags: google-app-engine, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

recently we deployed our site to google app engine and everything deployed successfully.
now we enable pagespeed in settings.

now problem.

its making loading css in html head section with some wried script tag instead of style tag..

1. i tried every and many confirmation settings but nothing works..
2. i want to load google fonts css early in html (not working, for now disable filters related to css because of issue 1)
3. i want it to combine all my js to one file and compress it. (not working)

here is page speed  configuration in yaml.

```
pagespeed:
  enabled_rewriters:
  - ConvertMetaTags
  - ElideAttributes
  - CollapseWhitespace
  - CombineJs
  - ProxyCss
  - InlineCss
  - MinifyCss
  - RemoveComments
  disabled_rewriters:
  - FlushSubresources
  - WebpOptimization
  - InlineImages
  - ImageStripColorProfile
  - ProxyImages
  - ProxyJs
  - ImageRecompressPng
  - ImageProgressiveJpeg
  - ImageConvertToJpeg
  - DeferJs
  - MoveCssToHead
  - InlineJs
  - InlinePreviewImages
```

here is website [www.justtotaltech.co.uk](http://www.justtotaltech.co.uk)

and sometime its load css in html after refreshing page one or two times..

is there any to configure more advance settings of pagespeed in app.yaml or somewhere else like pagespeed service and mod_pagespeed

or is there any way to use external pagespeed service for appengine instead of one inbuit with it. (i tried this but it don't fetch content from origin domain (app engine))

someone said in below comments for removing pagespeed section and now site don't have it. but nothing work at all.

Comment: Perhaps this is worthy of a bug in our issue tracker. What happens if you don't add the pagespeed section to the app.yaml file, but just enable the service with the defaults?

Comment: Ok i'll test and let u know. In next few hours.

Comment: its annoying now, some ago it was adding whole css in html now its not doing that but js are still in many files...and i didn't change anything since i posted this question.

Comment: now i removed pagespeed section and now its again loading all css in html and nothing changes...

Answer (score 7):

for the issue 3. I contacted pagespeed team for related issue previously and got the following response.

> CombineJs AND CombineCss are disabled automatically whenever FlushSubresources is enabled. this option is currently enabled by default.

So disable FlushSubresources first then combinJs rewriter will work.

Another thing worth to say is that you can actually preview the pagespeed results. 
For example:

view-source:http://www.justtotaltech.co.uk/services/software-development/?ModPagespeedFilters=combine_javascript,combine_css

It will be much easier to detect which filter cause the issue.

## Workable Page Speed Config

```
pagespeed:
  enabled_rewriters:
  - MinifyCss
  - CombineJs
  - CombineCss
  disabled_rewriters:
  - FlushSubresources
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts. but it didn't work? and filters works in urls but not working in yaml..

Comment: There are just too much rewriters in your yaml already. You can try my workable yaml config first.

Comment: ok uploaded your config now.... nothing worked..i think i should wait for it to be stable.... before i was also using few filters then wrote all here to disable unwanted filters.

Comment: did you flush your pagespeed cache after upload the config?

Comment: ohh yes.. now flushed that too.. but its still loading all css in page with script tag.

Answer (score 2):

Great question, as I am experiencing similar issues. I wanted to start by referring you to the google developer document page (which I am sure you have looked at):

- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig

As they note there, "App Engine's support for PageSpeed is an experimental, innovative, and rapidly changing new feature for Google App Engine. Unfortunately, being on the bleeding edge means that we may make backwards-incompatible changes to App Engine's support for PageSpeed. We will inform the community when this feature is no longer experimental."

Thus, I am not surprised to hear you experienced performance changes that were somewhat arbitrary. Paraphrasing from the developer docs, I see the following in terms of testing (as that is what I am trying to do for a custom application as well). To work through things, you might try to be very deliberate and try different test configurations (which I assume that you have already). That, said, if you haven't, and you want to try a new configuration, perhaps to test some "risky" optimizations, you might expect that you could do so in a test Application Version while your users continue to use the default Application Version. Unfortunately, since updating the test version's configuration applies to all versions, the "risky" settings are applied to the version that your users use, too. Instead, to try out these settings, you could:

- Turn off PageSpeed for your application, update PageSpeed configuration, and view your site using the PageSpeed chrome extension
- Copy the relevant parts of your application to a separate test application that has its own application ID and versions.

If you do find any specific solutions to the issue, please post them here!

Comment: I also might recommending adding this issue, along with documentation, to the AppEngine issues list. It will get some traction and attention for sure on that site: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Comment: means no solutions for now.. thanks..
i see its experimental but its too much experimental.
check it later and post issue there soon..

Comment: Too bad. Hope that at least my explanation provides some general guidance for preliminary testing. If you do find anything out, definitely share!